# Java dynamic function calling

Tags: java, reflection

I have a String array that contains names of method in the `yyyyyy` class

In the `xxxxxx` class I'm making a `yyyyyy` instance (say `obj`). Now I can call `obj.function_name()`, except I want to read `function_name` from the String array in a loop. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate ? Its not so clear to understand.

Comment: I believe the term you're looking for is "reflection".

Comment: Yes, using reflection and dynamic method invocation you can do this. If you google "java dynamic method invocation" you'll get some interesting hits. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3606401/Dynamic-LoadingReloading-of-Classes-and-Dynamic-Method-Invocation-Part-1.htm). This implements a kind of plotting language like you are describing.

Comment: and i'm also sure what he meant is this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Comment: @PeterTillemans ironically, i got here by searching  "java dynamic method calling" as this SO question is the first result of that search :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can, using [reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html). It is done by calling `Yyyy.class.getMethod("methodName").invoke(someArgs)`

You'd have to handle a bunch of exceptions, and your method must be `public`. Note that java coding conventions prefer `methodName` to `method_name`.

Using reflection, however, should be a last resort. You should be using more object-oriented techniques.

If you constantly need similar features, perhaps you can look at some dynamic language running on the java platform, like [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/)

Answer (score 26):

It's possible using reflection, although you should probably question your design somewhat if you need that sort of behavior. `Class.getMethod` takes a `String` for the method name and returns a `Method` object, which you can then call `.invoke` on to call the method

These Javadoc pages should be helpful:

- [`Class.getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...))
- [`Method.invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...))

Sample code (assuming the `yyyyyy` methods take one `int` argument, just to show argument passing):

```
yyyyyy obj = new yyyyyy();
String[] methodNames = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
for(String methodName : methodNames) {
    Method method = Class.forName("yyyyyy").getMethod(methodName, new Class[] {int.class});
    method.invoke(obj, 4); // 4 is the argument to pass to the method
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `obj.getClass()` in stead of `Class.forName("yyyyyy")` ?

Comment: links are messed up, try replacing ( with %28 and ) with %29

Comment: @Marc I actually prefer `yyyyyy.class` over either, but any work

Comment: @Michael Mrozek the advantage of using `obj.getClass()` is that it always returns the correct type, even after refactoring the `obj` variable.